# Compilation error character is missing-unix shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I need to find out 3 files in my UBM unix directory,if any one(CMUSER) file is available means,then i need to exit from my unix script,

Below is my unix shell script logic. Why am I getting compilation error?

```
cd /$UBCS
if [ -f /$UBM/CSUSER.LOCKED -o -f /$UBM/CSUSER.START]
     -o f /$UBM/CSUSER.UPDATE ];
then
   exit;
fi
```

my compilation error below

```
Enter script to execute: atm-autopbf
/rd23/gilbat/R2016/ubcs/atm-autopbf[38]: test: 0403-021 **A ] character is missing**
.
/rd23/gilbat/R2016/ubcs/atm-autopbf**[39]: -o:  **not found.****

 Not running C/S (SHELMATE MAXSESSIONS=0). Aborting ...

Press <ENTER> to continue:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script,

```
cd /$UBCS
if [ -f /$UBM/CSUSER.LOCKED -o -f /$UBM/CSUSER.START]
     -o f /$UBM/CSUSER.UPDATE ];
then
   exit;
fi
```

has a syntax error. You have unbalanced `[ ... ]` in the if-statement. You also need a space between `/$UBM/CSUSER.START` and the following `]`.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "/$UBCS" || exit 1

if [ -f "/$UBM/CSUSER.LOCKED" ] ||
   [ -f "/$UBM/CSUSER.START"  ] ||
   [ -f "/$UBM/CSUSER.UPDATE" ]
then
   exit
fi
```

Do try pasting your scripts into ShellCheck: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Also, you don't get *compilation* errors for shell scripts (as they are not compiled). They are *parsing* errors.